# Generate API signature in request header from parameters in the request body

Tags: owasp, zap

I'm using OWASP ZAP to test our API. We have a couple of POST endpoints which use an API Token and a shared secret for authentication and validating the request.

Some parameters of the request body are concatenated and hashed using the shared secret. This value is inserted into the request header.

How can I programatically generate this signature using OWASP ZAP?

**Request Header**

```
Content-Type: "application/json"
Accept: "application/json"
API-Key: {API_KEY}
Signature: {hash(field_one + field_two + field_three + SHARED_SECRET)}
```

**Request Body**

```
{
    "field_one": "abc",
    "field_two": "123",
    "field_three": "xyz"
}
```

The `SHARED_SECRET` is the *password* that is stored locally by the client and used to hash the three fields from the request.

It is stored on the server along with the API-Key so that requests can be identified and validated.

Answer (score 1):

Use an [HTTP Sender Script](https://github.com/zaproxy/community-scripts/tree/master/httpsender). Create it in the ZAP UI so that you can test it as you're writing it. First make sure you are just detecting the requests you want to change, then extract the field values you need and finally generate the hash. Keep testing at each stage to make sure its doing what you need. And if you need specific help theres always the [zaproxy-scripts](http://groups.google.com/group/zaproxy-scripts) group.